# Event listener for JRJC?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

Is there an example code to listen to jira events?
I'm using JRJC to create an issue, update it, etc.
But how do I listen to events (creation, updation of tickets/issues?

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get interested in the IssueEvent class from Atlassian SDK. When someone will edit the issue you can produce an event for example by script listeners which can run a script when they are triggered by one or more webhook events.

https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/7.6.1/com/atlassian/jira/event/issue/IssueEvent.html

Comment: Thankyou! Can you please provide an example if any? I can't find anything (proper java example). Appreciate your help :)